# Length of supporting ropes in a two-pulley system

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, energy

[image: Two pulley system]

Say I want to find the length of each component. I thought that in an ideal two-pulley system, each side of the supporting rope has a length 1/2 of the effort distance. So if I want to lift an object 3m in the air, I would think each supporting rope has a length of 3m and the effort distance is 6m. According to Kaplan MCAT Physics book, “If, for example, the crate must be lifted to a shelf 3 m above the ground, **then both sides of the supporting rope must be shortened by 3 meters**, and the only way to accomplish this is by pulling through  6 meters of rope”. Why aren’t the supporting ropes 3 m each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supporting ropes are not necessarily 3 metres each just because they are each shortened by 3 metres when the body is lifted through that height - they could be any length $l \geq 3$ metres and will just wind up 3 metres shorter, of length $l -3$ metres, once the action is complete. To summarise: "because the problem presented never implies it, and because that information is not needed to work out everything there is to know about the system".

This of course applies to an idealised system where we are assuming that

1. The physical components of the pulley, wheels, rope, et cetera, don't get in the way of one another, have negligible mass, and -
2. The supporting ropes are all perfectly vertical, such that the total length of rope reduced is exactly twice the displacement through which the weight is lifted.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very thorough answer and I appreciate you clarifying that this isn’t necessary for the problem because I assumed as much but I thought it would be good to understand what’s going on

Comment: I'm glad it has helped you. Do make sure to accept it as the answer (tick) to the question if you find that it has answered it satisfactorily; the system will mark this thread as answered.

Comment: I just did that